# Removing classes from list in Python

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, python-3.x, del

Why I can remove strings in list but not classes? Is it possible to do if there are classes in list? What is correct way to do this?

```
class Temp():
    def __init__(self, name, name2):
        self.n = name
        self.n2 = name2

cltemp1 = Temp("1", "2")
cltemp2 = Temp("3", "4")

x = ["1", "2"]
clx = [cltemp1, cltemp2]


def remove_string_from_class():
    global x

    for x[:] in x:
        del x[0]

remove_string_from_class()

print x


def remove_class_from_list():
    global clx

    for clx[:] in clx:
        del clx[0]

remove_class_from_list()

print clx
```

TypeError: can only assign an iterable

Comment: What do you mean by `for clx[:] in clx` and `for x[:] in x`?

Comment: same thing as in x[:] in x in earlier function. What I want it to mean is: For every element in list clx delete first element in this list until it's empty.

Comment: you might be have to try `for c in clx[:]:`

Comment: `while clx` also works. I'm curious, where does the `for x[:] in x` come from? It does look like it works on the string list, but I haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove every item from a list, simply use `lst = []`. If you need to mutate the list object without reassigning it, you can use `lst[:] = []` instead.

As for why your version doesn't work:

You are iterating over the list in the wrong manner. Iteration should look like `for var in lst`. The fact that your function works on the string list is mostly accidental: it replaces `x[:]` with the first string, and then deletes that string. It won't work correctly with all values (e.g. `x = ['11', '22']`), and as you saw it gives an error when the list contains non-iterables.

Comment: Thanks for help. It's even faster than previous anwer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to remove element from list

```
def remove_class_from_list():
    global clx
    for c in clx[:]:
        clx.remove(c)
```

Comment: This is a really inefficient (O(n^2)) and unpythonic method to do `ctx = []`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add these 2 methods to your class:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self

def next(self):
    if getattr(self, 'done', None):
        raise StopIteration
    self.done = True
    return 5
```

But I suggest that you learn python properly from some online tutorials on python.org

Comment: Primarily to motivate the user to learn about iterables and iterators. The exception raised and the accompanying error message could have made him curious.